# DataTable TypeError: d.trim is not a function

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I use DataTable in vue component.

```
$(this.$el).DataTable({
  data: this.rows,
                    columns: this.cols,
                    rowGroup: this.rowGroupData || null,
                .....
```

Call table:

```
if (this.dtHandle) {
                        this.dtHandle.clear();
                        this.dtHandle.rows.add(this.tableData);
                        console.log("data");
                        console.log(this.tableData);
                        this.dtHandle.draw();
                    }
```

But i got error on call   this.dtHandle.draw();

```
TypeError: d.trim is not a function
```

How fix it?

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/66042/d-trim-is-not-a-function-datetime-moment-js) but without a [mcve] this is just a guess. If this is the problem then this [commit](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/commit/addb0eb01330eb6109e75424a0db248e0b3b9144) fixes it.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. I have updated to version "datatables.net-bs4": "^ 1.10.22",
         "datatables.net-buttons": "^ 1.5.4",
         "datatables.net-plugins": "^ 1.10.21" but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Invalid data type in the table. Check before transferring to the table.